# Reusing variable in converting grammar to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

I'm not sure if reusing variable is allowed in CNF.


For example, I have this grammar not in CNF. So I have to convert it to CNF.

`1. S->abAB|abB|abA|ab
2. A->bAa|ba
3. B->BAa|bAa|ba|Ba|Aa|a`


For conversion, I'm using a convention where new variables and terminals are in the form

`(V1,V2,V3,...,Vk) for k > 0
Ti where i are terminals (a,b,c,...,z)`


`Introduce new terminals for each terminal in the grammar
S->(Ta)(Tb)AB|(Ta)(Tb)B|(Ta)(Tb)A|(Ta)(Tb)
A->(Tb)A(Ta)|(Tb)(Ta)
B->BA(Ta)|(Tb)A(Ta)|(Tb)(Ta)|B(Ta)|A(Ta)|a
Ta->a
Tb->b`


For the purpose of my question, I'm only focusing only on `B` productions due to the repetition of `A(Ta)`.

`...
B->BV1|(Tb)V2|(Tb)(Ta)|B(Ta)|A(Ta)|a
V1->A(Ta)
V2->A(Ta)
...`


See `V1` and `V2`, they have the same right-hand side that is `A(Ta)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Chomsky normal form" is something a grammar *is*, rather than the specific procedure used to make it. So nothing prevents you from reusing a symbol like that; the grammar will still be CNF if you do.